# Style Django form error message

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates

I'm trying to make django form defa error red and bold. For example, make "This field is required" red and bold. I saw error_css_class = 'error' but it's not working. 
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5//ref/forms/api/#django.forms.Form.error_css_class
Thank you!
This is my models.py

```
class RegiForm(forms.Form):
    error_css_class = 'error'
    DateInput = partial(forms.DateInput, {'class': 'datepicker'})
    email = forms.EmailField(max_length=75)
    first_name = forms.CharField(max_length=25)
    last_name = forms.CharField(max_length=25)
    address = forms.CharField(max_length=200)
```

This is my template:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
        <title>RegistrationForm</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Registration Form</h1>
        <form action="/login/regi/" method="POST">
            {% csrf_token %}
            {{ form.as_p }}
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What isn't working? Did you write some css to style the error class? Django will add the error class to the field with the error, but it won't automatically style the form for you.

Comment: Currently, I can get the form working and if I don't enter a thing in the required field in form, then there'll jump up a error message with bullet points like "This field is required". Just want to make this error message bold and red. I didn't add any css to the error class.

Comment: That's what the problem is. You need to write a css rule to do the styling Django doesn't do any styling for you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check the class name in the source code browser.
You can try to change the class name like that:

```
class MyForm(forms.Form):
    error_css_class = "error"
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.

Comment: It does.See the source code will help @Penocky to understand the input structure and error message made by django in order to add style it.

Comment: Changing the class won't style the error message if @Penocky hasn't written any CSS to style the message in the first place, which is what the problem is.

Comment: I agree, it was just solution to help him understanding. But for me the problem come from CSS side

Comment: I kind of get what you mean. Just wonder how I am supposed to add css for form? I tried directly link a css in my template but not work. Should I revise  a errorlist or any tutorial for that? Thank you!

Comment: I add css in the html and it's fixed. Thank you!

Answer (score 11):

Just add this `CSS` to change error message color:
`.errorlist
    {
        color: red;
    }`
                                                                               or if you want to change field border color then
 `.error input, .error select {
border: 2px red solid;
}`

Comment: This strangely does not work.

Answer (score 6):

I know this is an old question but I needed it as a beginner.

You can extend the **ErrorList** class in the

> django.forms.utils

to style it as you wish.
In my case I wanted it as divs and Bootstrap alerts.

So I did this in **forms.py**

```
class DivErrorList(ErrorList):
    def __str__(self):
        return self.as_divs()

    def as_divs(self):
        if not self:
            return ''
        return '<div class="errorlist">%s</div>' % ''.join(['<div class="error alert alert-danger mt-1">%s</div>' % e for e in self])
```

and in the **views.py**

> form = AddToCartForm(error_class=DivErrorList)

see the documentaion: [customizing-the-error-list-format](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/forms/api/#customizing-the-error-list-format)

Answer (score 5):

To change the style of the error_message:

1st: Inspect the element of the error_message then copy its class

2nd: Add the style you want ...

In my case.... the class of the error_message is help-block

```
<style>
.help-block{color:red;
            font-weight:bold;
}
</style>
```

JUST DON'T FORGET TO PUT IT INSIDE YOUR {% block content %} or {% block body %} on your html if you extended the base.html or else... it wont work

3rd: That's All :)